# Can we customize SMS Template for Azure AD B2C OTP

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, one-time-password

Can we customize SMS Template for Azure AD B2C OTP?
Currently the default template looks like below:

"Use verification code xxxxx for [System name]"

Is it possible to change the template for the SMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use the custom SMS template within B2C, you have to use an external mail provider. The built in email verification has a separate combined OTP and mail provider service that is not able to be decoupled.

Integrate a custom SMS provider in Azure Active Directory B2C (Azure AD B2C) to customized SMS' to users that perform multi factor authentication to your application. By using DisplayControls (currently in preview) and a third-party SMS provider, you can use your own contextualised SMS message, custom Phone Number, as well as support localization and custom one-time password (OTP) settings.

Custom SMS integration requires the use of a third-party SMS provider such as Twilio or your own custom SMS provider.

Check this for more information [Custom SMS verification in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/custom-sms-displaycontrol/readme.md)

Comment: does the MS SMS provider support different locales?